# Is there any support in mathcomp/ssreflect for classical logic

Tags: coq, ssreflect

For example, coq has in its standard library a Classical package with lemmas in classical logic such as ones that relate forall and exists (https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Logic.Classical_Pred_Type.html).

My question is if there is any support like that in mathcomp or ssreflect itself. All I have found so far is a few definitions and lemmas in https://github.com/coq/stdlib2/blob/master/src/bool.v#L548

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is anything along those lines in the basic mathcomp libraries. The closest might be the `classically` operator in `ssrbool`, which mimics classical reasoning in intuitionistic logic.  However, the experimental mathcomp analysis library assumes classical axioms and has results like the ones you mentioned (https://github.com/math-comp/analysis/blob/master/theories/boolp.v).